# What is the invalid URI error from SpamAssassin actually matching?

Tags: regex, spamassassin

I'm trying to debug some emails that are getting sent to the Spam Folder by SpamAssassin and I encountered an error that I'm having trouble fixing.  The problem seems to be that there's an invalid URI somewhere in the email, but I'm not sure how to find it.  Maybe if I could figure out what the error is matching, it would help.

This is the actual error I'm getting back:

```
0.6      SARE_OBFU_AMP          invalid character within URI host/domain
```

Did some digging on Google and it looks like this is the REGEX that the rule is based on *([Source](http://mta.org.ua/spamassassin/stuff/spamass-rules/spamass-rules-20050821/70_sare_obfu1.cf))*

```
m{(?!(?:mailto:|\#).*)^(?:https?://)?[^/\?]{4,40}\&}i
```

So the actual question is: **What does the error I'm getting actually mean and how can I actually identify the bad URI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such email contains some url/link address that contains `&` character with no leading `/` or `?` character before the `&`. For example *http://www.domain.com&something-else*

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem thanks to you!  How did you know that was the issue? Docs or just past experience?